# Don't want the button to remain selected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
<li><a href="/help/index.htm" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a></li>
```

But when I click it, the button remain selected. 
How can I change it to say don't remain selected, I just want it to have the hover effect but not to remain selected.

Comment: better you show it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

On `bootstrap` you have to do manual deselect of button using Javascript.

```
$("button").removeClass("active");// call it after the button click event
```

Comment: when it is darker ( like when I hover over or just click on it to select it ) if I do inspect element, I don't see Active class

Comment: on `hover` do you need to deselect it? then you need to write some css also for `hoverout`

Comment: no on hoverover is good, I want it to change color liek it does now...just when I click it I don't want the color effect

Comment: so WHICH element should I actually target?  the gyperlink ? the li ? the fa font aweosme one ? which one ?

Comment: try with css: `button:focus:active {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    color: #ccc;
}` and see if it works